# Bad Request Response for Microsoft Intune Device Actions

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api, odata

Our company using Microsoft Graph API to retrieve data about devices. Now we are trying to use it for intune device actions but either we are getting error messages even though we followed everything at Microsoft Graph API docs or nothing happens even though API response success.

1. we checked the permissions and all needed permissions are given.
2. we followed docs and tried multiple versions of API URLs mentioned in docs but none of them worked.
3. we also tried the beta version of API but it didn't work either.
4. We found some readings about some of these actions work specifically on some OS type or some specific device permissions but we can't find detail on docs.

So we want to use **all** actions on Intune devices but details on docs are not helpful.

*I am getting the following error on related actions*

POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{usersId}/managedDevices/{managedDeviceId}/shutDown](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BusersId%7D/managedDevices/%7BmanagedDeviceId%7D/shutDown)

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "{  \"_version\": 3,  \"Message\": \"An error has occurred - Operation ID (for customer support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - Activity ID: 2e274924-5fe1-453f-d869-671abf922cfd - Url: https://fef.amsub0502.manage.microsoft.com/DeviceFE/StatelessDeviceFEService/deviceManagement/managedDevices%28%27e002cd5b-f97f-4212-b0b6-38ae3e77938e%27%29/microsoft.management.services.api.shutDown?api-version=5021-04-16\",  \"CustomApiErrorPhrase\": \"\",  \"RetryAfter\": null,  \"ErrorSourceService\": \"\",  \"HttpHeaders\": \"{}\"}",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-05-31T08:44:54",
            "request-id": "c869f3f9-def1-4d7f-93af-16b458bc0b17",
            "client-request-id": "2e274924-5fe1-453f-d869-671abf922cfd"
        }
    }
}
```

POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{usersId}/managedDevices/{managedDeviceId}/remoteLock](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BusersId%7D/managedDevices/%7BmanagedDeviceId%7D/remoteLock)

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "{  \"_version\": 3,  \"Message\": \"An error has occurred - Operation ID (for customer support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - Activity ID: 6676f0a0-8895-302e-672b-3cdb66092428 - Url: https://fef.amsub0502.manage.microsoft.com/DeviceFE/StatelessDeviceFEService/deviceManagement/managedDevices%28%27e002cd5b-f97f-4212-b0b6-38ae3e77938e%27%29/microsoft.management.services.api.remoteLock?api-version=2021-04-07\",  \"CustomApiErrorPhrase\": \"\",  \"RetryAfter\": null,  \"ErrorSourceService\": \"\",  \"HttpHeaders\": \"{}\"}",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-05-31T08:56:10",
            "request-id": "a360b06a-fb02-4af3-9f8f-06e138b76288",
            "client-request-id": "6676f0a0-8895-302e-672b-3cdb66092428"
        }
    }
}
```

*I am getting a success response following actions but nothing happens to the devices*

POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{usersId}/managedDevices/{managedDeviceId}/rebootNow](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BusersId%7D/managedDevices/%7BmanagedDeviceId%7D/rebootNow)
POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0//deviceManagement/managedDevices/{managedDeviceId}/wipe](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0//deviceManagement/managedDevices/%7BmanagedDeviceId%7D/wipe)